# The component isn't updating when I pass in a filtered variable on a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I was trying to implement a filter that is controlled by a search bar input. So I think part of the problem is that I have this filter hooked on a timer so that while the user is typing into the search bar, it isn't re-running for each letter typed in.

What it is currently doing is that after the item is typed in the search bar, the timer goes off and the filters are working but it doesn't appear that the app is re-rendering with the new filtered variable.

I suspect that it might have something to do with useEffect but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it and it wasn't working out for whatever I was doing with it.

Here's the code:

```
const RecipeCards = (props) => {
  const inputTypingRef = useRef(null);
    let preparingElement = props.localRecipes;
    let cardElement;
    let elementsSorted;

const ingredientCountSort = (recipes) => {
    elementsSorted = ...
}
    
    const elementRender = (element) => {
        cardElement = element.map((rec) => (
            <RecipeCard
                name={rec.name}
                key={rec.id}
                ingredients={rec.ingredients}
                tags={rec.tags}
                removeRecipe={() => props.onRemoveIngredients(rec.id)}
                checkAvail={props.localIngredients}
            />
        ));
        ingredientCountSort(cardElement);
    };
  
  if (inputTypingRef.current !== null) {
        clearTimeout(inputTypingRef.current);
    }
    if (props.searchInput) {
        inputTypingRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            inputTypingRef.current = null;

            if (props.searchOption !== "all") {
                preparingElement = props.localRecipes.filter((rec) => {
                    return rec[props.searchOption].includes(props.searchInput);
                });
            } else {
                preparingElement = props.localRecipes.filter((rec) => {
                    return rec.includes(props.searchInput);
                });
            }
        }, 600);
    }
    elementRender(preparingElement);

    return (
        <div className={classes.RecipeCards}>{!elementsSorted ? <BeginPrompt /> : elementsSorted}</div>
    );
};
```

Don't worry about ingredientCountSort() function. It's a working function that just rearranges the array of JSX code.

Comment: at first glance, you did not return anything in your timeout function. your filter simply return the values to "preparingElement", you need to return preparingElements to somewhere, either through setting state or assigning the value to some ref. At this point, your elementRender(preparingElement) doesn't do anything since it's outside the setTimeout function.

Comment: I made an oversight. the conditional should be based on searchOption, not searchInput. Regardless, shouldn't make a difference and my question still stands.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do elementsSorted is not changed, so there's nothing to render. You need to do something like const [elementsSorted, setelementssorted] = useState(false); If there isn't any state updated, there's no render retriggered.

Comment: No the ternary works. elementsSorted is a value provided by the ingredientCountSort() function that I said not to worry about. I left out the code for ingredientCountSort() because I thought it was irrelevant. Also, it doesn't seem like the return value within the timer is doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used useEffect() and an additional useRef() while restructuring the order of functions

```js
const RecipeCards = (props) => {
    //const inputTypingRef = useRef(null);
    let preparingElement = props.localRecipes;
    let finalElement;
    const [enteredFilter, setEnteredFilter] = useState(props.searchInput);
    let elementsSorted;
    const [elementsFiltered, setElementsFiltered] = useState();
    const refTimer = useRef();
    const filterActive = useRef(false);
    let cardElement;

    useEffect(() => {
        setEnteredFilter(props.searchInput);
        console.log("updating filter");
    }, [props.searchInput]);

    const filterRecipes = (recipes) => {
        if (enteredFilter && !filterActive.current) {
            console.log("begin filtering");
            if (refTimer.current !== null) {
                clearTimeout(refTimer.current);
            }
            refTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
                refTimer.current = null;

                if (props.searchOption !== "all") {
                    setElementsFiltered(recipes.filter((rec) => {
                        return rec.props[props.searchOption].includes(enteredFilter);
                    }))
                } else {
                    setElementsFiltered(recipes.filter((rec) => {
                        return rec.props.includes(enteredFilter);
                    }))
                }
                filterActive.current = true;
                console.log(elementsFiltered);
            }, 600);
        }else if(!enteredFilter && filterActive.current){
            filterActive.current = false;
            setElementsFiltered();
        }
        finalElement = elementsFiltered ? elementsFiltered : recipes;
    };

    const ingredientCountSort = (recipes) => {
        console.log("sorting elements");
        elementsSorted = recipes.sort((a, b) => {
            ...
        filterRecipes(elementsSorted);
    };

    const elementRender = (element) => {
        console.log("building JSX");
        cardElement = element.map((rec) => (
            <RecipeCard
                name={rec.name}
                key={rec.id}
                ingredients={rec.ingredients}
                tags={rec.tags}
                removeRecipe={() => props.onRemoveIngredients(rec.id)}
                checkAvail={props.localIngredients}
            />
        ));
        ingredientCountSort(cardElement);
    };

    //begin render ///////////////////          ///         ///         ///         ///         ///

    elementRender(preparingElement);
    console.log(finalElement);

    return (
        <div className={classes.RecipeCards}>{!finalElement[0] ? <BeginPrompt /> : finalElement}</div>
    );
};
```

There might be redundant un-optimized code I want to remove on a brush-over in the future, but it works without continuous re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Following up to my comment in original question. elementsSorted is changed, but it doesn't trigger a re-render because there isn't a state update.

instead of

```
let elementsSorted
```

and

```
elementsSorted = ...
```

try useState

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const RecipeCards = (props) => {
....
const [ elementsSorted, setElementsSorted ] = useState();

const ingredientCountSort = () => {
     ...
    setElementsSorted(...whatever values elementsSorted supposed to be here)
  
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: This just creates an infinite re-render loop

Comment: it doesn't create infinite re-render loop. It only create infinite re-render if you call setElementsSorted INSIDE the return statement.  This is the most basis use of useState. If you are facing infinite loop then it's not problem with useState but problem with your codes, which you need to be more open so we can correct them.

Comment: I tried it myself. It broke the app. I did use SetElementsSorted. And as stated twice before, my problem has nothing to do with elementsSorted, it's the timer.

Comment: If it causes a infinite loop, then yes there's a error in your codes, not useState itself. useState is like oxygen of React functional components, you need it to trigger those re-renders, but also make sure it's not a loop.

Comment: I'm manipulating the array of JSX code within ingredientCountSort, so that on its own is creating a re-render. And as stated three times now, elementsSorted and ingredientCountSort() is not relevant to my problem if elementRender() that comes before ingredientCountSort() is not taking in the filtered values after the timer expires.

Comment: as stated in origin comments, your elementRender(preparingElement); is being called OUTSIDE the timeout, so it's not calling.